# Normalisation in tensor networks

Tags: simulation, tensor

I am trying to implement the iTEBD algorithm for the $PXP$ model, i.e, the hamiltonian is

$$H = \sum_iP_{i-1}X_iP_{i+1}.$$

Here $P$ is the projector onto the ground state and $X$ is the usual pauli x matrix.

I aim to time evolve a certain initial state and record certain observables. To do so, I initialized my iMPS (infinite Matrix Product State), and as a check, I took the overlap of this with itself. As I expected, this gave me a result of 1. However, it appears that as I time evolve my state, the normalization strays further from unity, and by the last time step, it is of the order 1e5. I know that we perform a truncation in each time step, but my question is can this introduce such a large error?  Or is there a specific step where we have to normalize the MPS that I am missing?